# I was looking at an app from the US app store, now I can't find out how to change store back to UK?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, apple-id

When trying to update apps I had previously installed I get the message "Account not in this store", saying I must leave the US store.

My region is UK and I have Apple iD and valid payment for UK.

How do I change back to the UK store?

I even tried creating a new Apple iD and still have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on iOS 12:

Go to the AppStore. At the bottom tap on *today*.

Then tap the avatar in the top-right as show below:

[image: avatar]

Then click on your name/email at the top.

Then you should be able to change your AppStore/check your country or region there:

[image: country and region]

Comment: Thank you, but my region here is already the UK.

Comment: @RyanFleming Is there an option to change the AppStore to uk?

Comment: After signing in and out after changing the region the app store reverted to UK. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @RyanFleming No problem. If my answer helped feel free to press the tick next to my answer